# Getting lines of C code in files

Tags: code-coverage, gcov, gcovr

We are using gcov and gcovr.py to get coverage reports for our tests. Not all the source files are tested at all and therefore those aren't mentioned in gcovr report. Now I'd like to calculate overall coverage for whole code base nevertheless.

From the reports I can get lines covered but I'd also need to get number of C code lines in those files which aren't tested. What would be the possibilities to to get lines of C code in files inside code directory?

Comment: Do you mean 'non-comment (non-blank) lines of code'?  If you just mean 'lines in the file', then `wc -l` gives you the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `cloc`, which will count lines of code in files or process a directory: https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will fit this purpose. Maybe there will be small inaccuracies but shouldn't be too bad. I tried to find something similar but written in python to include it in my script "natively" but could not find anything.

Comment: @burm: Yeah. I know the feeling with regard to things that aren't written in Python or Haskell. But it's better than nothing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to what I know, when you generate coverage report using gcovr it gives out this kind of report in console

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: ...../src/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/A/A1/xyz.cpp                            1609       2     0%   97,99,101....
src/A/A2/abcg.cpp                            271       4     1%   .......
src/B/B1/mnop.cpp                             74       2     2%   34,42,56-.....
src/B/B2/wrds.cpp                           1533       6     0%   76,83,85-.....
src/C/C1/abcdefg.cpp                        1079       8     0%   143,150,152.....
```

This has all the liine numbers which were not executed relevant  to each source file.
Hope it helped :)